# Firebase Hosting - Emails not coming through

Tags: email, firebase, dns, hosting

I followed the procedures and set up firebase hosting for my domain: when the user types in domainname.com or www.domainname.com the site hosted on firebase is opened.

But my emails do no longer come through :(
Error messages include

Action: delayed - Status: 4.4.1 - 
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect*

It will try a couple of times and then fail.

The domainname is registered with awardspace.com. There, I have the possibility to set DNS entries for domainname.com, mail.domainname.com, www.domainname.com and mx.domainname.com

Note: I can sent emails from info@domainname.com

Comment: Can you share the DNS lookup of the domain and detailed error?

Comment: Would like to share but avoid public sharing. Could we get in direct contact?
Ways to solve the issue would be shared here.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting DNS records at my provider, disconnecting the domainname from firebase hosting and connecting the domain again from scratch solved the issue for me.

Note: the previous connection used CNAME records, no longer used / needed by firebase.